# How to convert aerospike binMap to array of struct in Go lang?

Tags: go, aerospike

I am reading all record set from aerospike set as below:

```
stmt :=  as.NewStatement(namespace, set)
recordSet, err := db.AerospikeClient.Query(nil,stmt)
```

now I want to map the result records to the struct of the set. How can I do that?

I tried mapping record.Bins to struct but it didn't worked.
The result should be array of below struct:

```
type MyStruct struct {
  name           string     `as:"userId" json:"userId"`
  UserList  []UserList `as:"userList" json:"userList"`
  CreatedAt        int64      `as:"createdAt" json:"createdAt"`
  UpdatedAt        int64      `as:"updatedAt" json:"updatedAt"`
}
```

Here is the code that I tried:

```
for rec := range recordSet.Records {
    var myStruct MyStruct
    jsonString, err := json.Marshal(rec.Bins)
    if err != nil {
        utils.LogErr("","", "Error occurred while marshling all the records from old set to my struct", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    err = json.Unmarshal(jsonString,&myStruct)
}
```

It is giving below error:

> "error":"json: unsupported type: map[interface {}]interface {}"

Comment: Where is your code? What didn't work about it?

Comment: I am not able to figure out a way to map the recordSet to array of my struct :(. What I initially tried was converting the record.Bins to json object and then tried to unmarshal it to struct object. But that didn't work. If there is any other way then let me know. Any references/examples? @Flimzy

Comment: Please show us your code, and explain what didn't work.

Comment: why down vote??

Comment: updated the question with the code in which I am trying to map the individual records to struct @Flimzy

Comment: That's an improvement, thanks. But it's not complete code... where are you defining a variable of type `map[interface{}]interface{}`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153258/discussion-between-dipen-adroja-and-flimzy).

Comment: Is the error you're getting from Marshal, or Unmarshal?

Comment: From Marshal @mkopriva

Comment: That means that one of the [BinMap](https://godoc.org/github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go#BinMap) values in `Record.Bins` is of the type `map[interface{}]interface{}`, which, as you can see by the error, is unsupported by `encoding/json`. So marshaling/unmarshaling is not gonna help you, you'll have to look for a different solution.

Comment: ohh... thanks... I am trying to map individual element by iterating the map.. I will let you know if that works